# Unable to run Nginx HTTPS webserver on Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

I have been trying build a Docker container to set Nginx webserver on my custom domain, e.g. `example.com`, using SSL. This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:latest as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
  server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
  }
}
```

Then:

```
sudo docker build . -t app
sudo docker run -v /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/:ro -d -p 443 app
```

However, when I visit `http://example.com` or `https://example.com` the website shows nothing, and then the connection times out.  But when I visit the external IP address `xx.xxx.xx.xxx/` the Nginx default page is shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you check DNS for example.com domain, try to ping example.com domain ?

Comment: From `Dockerfile`  file I guess you missed command that will be running once container is started.

Comment: Hi, pinging does work. But the browser keeps loading.

Comment: I'm trying to deploy a Vue app, the `Dockerfile` is based on the official Vue CLI page https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx

Comment: did you run `docker run -d -p 80:80 my-app` and check to see `nginx` container is live or not ?

Comment: `-p 80:80` gives me `docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nice_lederberg (ca3e0fa8aa210cf89c28829a9c532dffcc412de23a4e5d10a1b5fe69cfcbf2c4): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use.`

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was easier than I thought.

First of all, I uninstalled nginx on the host machine, so as to allow connections on port 80 from the container (you don't really need to uninstall, just stop the nginx service with `sudo service nginx stop`).

Then, the problem was on the following line, on the **port** parameter:

`sudo docker run -v /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/:ro -d -p 443 app`

Changed it from `-p 443` to `-p 80:80 -p 443:443` to enable both HTTP and HTTPS connections, and now it is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nginx installed on host and its listening on port 80. So used another port

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 my-app
```

Then try to access `http://example.com:8080` again.

Or shut down nginx on host and use port 80.

Comment: Just uninstalled nginx on the host server. Problem remains. I'm starting to believe it is something related to my nginx config?

Comment: can you show the output `docker ps` to see which container is running ?

Comment: Sure (image is `haxmania-site` instead of `app`)

```CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                   NAMES
dad84c0c1ed4   haxmania-site   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp   hungry_curran
```

Comment: check `docker logs -f  dad84c0c1ed4` while you are accessing http://example.com:8080

Comment: It gives 400.
`[27/Sep/2021:03:26:28 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03\xC6]\xF6\xEE" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"`
I did some research on this error and found this problem very similar to mine: https://serverfault.com/questions/961545/nginx-returns-400-on-https-requests.
But does not apply to my problem, since I am already using `listen 443 ssl`.

Comment: check port 8080 first, if its done, move to check SSL

Comment: This log output goes for `sudo docker run -v /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/:ro -d -p 8080:80 haxmania-site`

Comment: I think problem is solved. Instead of `-p 443`, passing `-p 80:80 -p 443:443` to enable both http and https. Will check if everything is ok.